# Arquilian integration tests with JUnit and TestNG

Tags: junit, testng, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I want in my multi-moduled project to have integration tests using JUnit and TestNG containers. Is it possible to do that without this error:

> Multiple TestRunners found, only one allowed. Check your classpath

I get this error when I have together below dependencies for

> arquillian-junit-container
>
> arquillian-testng-container

Comment: Why do you need both?

Comment: It would be simpler to have one but I want both of them

Comment: Weak explanation that you want? What does JUnit offer that Testng doesnt have?